# Angular Server Side Rendering ; How to keep it running forever?

Tags: angular5

I am trying to host an angular server side rendering app. Whenever I try this command `npm run serve:ssr` it runs fine and after a while it stops automatically. I just have 2 questions.

1. How do i keep it running forever ?
2. Is that the right way to do for a production ready app?

   Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow angular's advice and discourage node and express as servers. But sometimes you have to do it. If you do care about security ( a lot ) I would crawl the entire site and drop the results in a static NGINX server.

In either case you should use angular universal with a grain of salt.

And to keep things runing forever you can turn the `npm serve:ssr` into a deamon (unix) so that the system keeps it on. Or simple change it to : `while true; do npm serve:ssr; done`